# How to use boolean variable from separate activity in if- else statement of another activity

Tags: java, android

I am updating the value of boolean variable in one activity on a button click and use the result in splash screen activity but it is giving a null pointer exception. What am I doing wrong and how can i fix it?

I have created 2 buttons and the value value of it change w.r.t which button is pressed. and the use the boolean in another activity. But it gives error

```
//The Activity where boolein updates on button click
public class ProfileSelection extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private Button signs, text;

    boolean impaired = false; //Boolean that i neededto update

    //FIrebase
    FirebaseUser currentUser;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_selection);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_page_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("  Hand Talk Mediator");
        getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.logosmall);

        text = (Button)findViewById(R.id.with_text);
        signs = (Button)findViewById(R.id.with_signs);



            text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    impaired =false;

                    Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileSelection.this,MainActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            });
            signs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    impaired = true;

                    Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileSelection.this,MainActivitySign.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            });


    }

//The activity where boolean is needed in condition
public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static int SPLASH_TIMEOUT = 1200;
    Context context;
    private boolean selection = ((ProfileSelection)context).impaired;
    //private boolean selection = true;

    //FIrebase
    FirebaseUser currentUser;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                if (currentUser == null){
                    sendUsertoLoginActivity();
                }
                else
                {
                    if (selection== false)
                    {
                        Intent homeIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(homeIntent);
                        finish();
                    }

                    else if (selection == true)
                    {
                        Intent homeIntentSign = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivitySign.class);
                        startActivity(homeIntentSign);
                        finish();
                    }

                    else {
                        Intent loginIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,LoginActivity.class);
                       startActivity(loginIntent);
                       finish();
                   }
                },SPLASH_TIMEOUT);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you have defined the boolean in SplashScreen is probably not what you want.
Define it like

```
boolean selection;
```

Also putExtra with your intent like this in ProfileSelection activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ProfileSelection.this,MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("Impaired", impaired);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Here "Impaired" works as key and variable impaired works as value just like in HashMaps

Now go to SplashScreen activity and in onCreate() method, initialize selection

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 selection = intent.getExtra("Impaired");
```

Now selection variable contains value of impaired from first activity and you can use it throughout the second activity.

Comment: When i used intent.putExtra in onCreate() method , it gave me null pointer exception so used it in else statement where the selection is used, but now after splash screen, selection variable always turns to false

Comment: Did you use putExtra in both onClickListener in ProfileSelection  activity. If I am not wrong, you might have used it for text.setOnClickListener only. Do the same in signs.setOnClickListener also. It will work

Comment: Yes, I did use putExtra on both click listener. To test the problem, I changed variable impaired from boolean to int and initialized it with 0 and changed its value to 1 on text.setOnClickListener and to 2 on signs.setOnClickListener but after first time execution, the value of 'impaired' variable always turn to 0. It is my guess that it is because the ProfileSelectionActivity comes after the SplashScreenActivity but I am confused.

Comment: Was it working while Data type of impaired was boolean?
Also check while changing impaired from boolean to int, did you also change the Data type of selection in the SplashScreen activity from boolean to int?

Comment: I did and it only worked after first execution after closing and re opening the app, it always crashed. However I stored the boolean value in firebase in ProfileSelectionActivity and call its value in SplashScreenActivity and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of direct access to the impaired value:

```
private boolean selection = ((ProfileSelection)context).impaired;
```

you should pass it through intent by Bundle. Then extract it in the activity by `getIntent().getBundleExtra().getBoolean()`